# Sum of integers in an array

Tags: java, arrays

So, basically, the questions asks me to find the sum of the numbers in an array. Except the number '13' is very unlucky, so it does not count '13' and the number that come immediately after a '13'.

This is what I did:

```
public int sum13(int[] nums) {
  int d = 0;
  int sum = 0;

  for (int i=0;i<nums.length;i++){
    if(nums[i] == 13){
    d = i;
    break;
    }
    else{
    d = nums.length;
    }
  }
  for(int i=0;i<d;i++){
   sum = sum + nums[i];
  }
  return sum;
}
```

Even though I pass most of the tests, I still can't understand how to exclude the number right next to the 13 from the sum.

For example, sum13({1, 2, 2, 1, 13}) → 6 PASSES!
sum13({13, 1, 13}) → 0 PASSES! 
But, sum13({13, 1, 2, 13, 2, 1, 13}) → 3 RETURNS 0 instead as it stops at the first instance of 13.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Why are you using two loops? If the number is `13`, just don't add it or the next number to the sum, like this:

```
public int sum13(int[] nums) {
    int sum = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < nums.length; i++) {
        if (nums[i] == 13) {
            i++;
        } else {
            sum = sum + nums[i];
        }
    }
    return sum;
}
```

Comment: Ahh...so if I want to exclude the number right next to 13, I just have to increment i by 2 instead? (i =+ 2)

Comment: `i` is already incremented each iteration, and no addition is done when `13` is encountered. So,  by writing `i++`, we skip the number after `13` too.

Answer (score 4):

As per your question you exclude if the number is 13 & its immediate successor. So when you find 13 increment the loop counter once more:

```
 for(int i=0;i<nums.length;i++){
   if(nums[i] == 13) {
     i++;
    }
   else {
     sum = sum + nums[i];
   }
  }
```

This will naturally skip the next element of 13,  if there's one within the array.

Answer (score 2):

How about summing directly in the first `for` loop? Shorter, easier and faster way :)

```
public int sum13(int[] nums) {
  int sum = 0;

  for (int i=0;i<nums.length;i++){
    if (nums[i] != 13) {
      sum += nums[i];
    } else {
      i++;
    }
  }
  return sum;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Did you hear what `continue` does?

```
if(nums[i] == 13){
     d = i;
     continue;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public int sum13(int[] nums) {
      boolean skip = false;
      int sum = 0;

      for (int i=0;i<nums.length;i++){
        if(nums[i] == 13){
            skip=true;
            continue;
        }
        else{
        if(skip) {
            skip=false;
            continue;
        }
        sum+=nums[i];
        }
      }

      return sum;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

What you are actually doing is stopping at the first occurrence of 13.

try this:

```
public int sum13(int[] nums) {
    int sum = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < nums.length; i++) {
        if (nums[i] == 13) {
            i++;
        } else {
            sum += nums[i];
        }
    }

    return sum;
}
```

I didn't test it but it should work...

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
   public int mySum(int[] nums, int except) {
        int sum = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < nums.length; i++) {
             sum += (nums[i] == except) ? 0: nums[i];
        }
        return sum;
    }
```

Then

```
mySum(nums, 13)
```

Answer (score 0):

use the continue; statement when the value equals to 13.

```
public int sum13(int[] nums) {
  int sum = 0;
  for (int i=0;i<nums.length;i++){
    if(nums[i] == 13){
       continue;
    }
    else{
       sum = sum + nums[i];
    }
  }
  return sum;
}
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/privileges/comment).

Comment: @guerda thanks for advising me. i have added the necessary code block.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
public int sum(int[] nums) {
    int sum = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < nums.length;) {
        if (nums[i] == 13)
            i = i + 2;
        else {
            sum = sum + nums[i];
            i++;
        }
    }
    return sum;
}
```